# How to append text in existing values of items in autocomplete?

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

In automplete i want to append text in result
for ex: if i type MU in textbox then am getting result like MUMBAI,MUBRA
But in that Result I want to show MUMABI FOR RENT,MUMBAI FOR SALE,MUMBRA FOR RENT,
MUBRA FOR SALE.
So in autocomplete how can i show above result?

```
    source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
            url: "/Homepage/Default.aspx/GetKeywordSearchResults",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ keyword: $("[id*='txtSmartSearch']").val(), postingpurposeid: currentSelectedTab }),
            success: function (data) {

                response($.map(JSON.parse(data.d), function (item) {


                    return {
                        value: item.result ,
                        label: item.result 
                    }
                }));
            },
            failure: FailureHandler
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>JQuery AutoComplete TextBox Demo</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><h1>AutoComplete Textbox</h1>
City:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#txtCity").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
var param = { cityName: $('#txtCity').val() };
$.ajax({
url: "Default.aspx/GetCities",
data: JSON.stringify(param),
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
success: function (data) {
response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
return {
value: item
}
}))
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus);
}
});
},
minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added a WebMethod "GetCities" in default.aspx.cs to  call it in Source of JQuery Autocomplete

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCities(string cityName)
    {
        List<string> City = new List<string>();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%{0}%'", cityName);
        //Note: you can configure Connection string in web.config also.
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS2008R2; initial Catalog = NORTHWND; Integrated Security = true"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    City.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        return City;
    }
```

see here ->http://dotnetcodepress.com/Articles/ASP-dot-net/jquery-ui-autocomplete-textbox-from-database-in-asp-net